# Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project for youtube search list

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api

i implement youtube search list from  [Youtube Search List](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/Search.java)

but coming this error

> Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project

Code:-

```
youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport,jsonFactory, new HttpRequestInitializer() 
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    }
}).setApplicationName("youtube-cmdline-search-sample").build();


String queryTerm = getInputQuery();

// Define the API request for retrieving search results.
YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

// Set your developer key from the Google Developers Console for

String apiKey = ""; //i have server key and browser key
search.setKey(apiKey);
search.setQ(queryTerm);

search.setType("video");

search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution:-**

I created project from [here](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?noredirect) old developer console site.

I used browser key from Old developer console site.

Comment: Wow! This had me stumped for ages. Can't believe the new console just doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I disabled the API and then re-enabled it and then it worked.

Answer (score -1):

You need to activate your google api for the youtube application. By logging into Google Developers account. Select API and a list of all google api's should be listed you need to enable the youtube api and paste in the api access key associated with your account.

```
// Set your developer key from the Google Developers Console for

String apiKey = ""; //i have server key and browser key
search.setKey(apiKey);
search.setQ(queryTerm)
```

Comment: Now enter your API Key in the String apikey = (Your API goes here) and that should solve your issue.

Comment: i added browser key and server key but coming same error

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/   Try implementing this library since its updated for v3 support.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ensured that in your Developers Console, the field for referrers is empty?

Answer (score -1):

I received this error when I created a "Server Key" and the IP I whitelisted didn't match the the client's IP (where I ran the application).

Answer (score -2):

Wow! Yes, use the Old Developers Console. I worked all day on this before I finally found this answer. On the New Developers Console there's a link to the old one. Generate a new key in the old console and it'll work! This sucks.

Comment: Who are leaving these ratings on my answer? Pls explain. I simply confirmed what AnilPatel posted, and added a bit of detail. You know, it can sound flaky to state a workaround like AnilPatel posted, and I simply confirmed it. I did what he said and it worked for me, that's all I can say...